# MEAN Web Development

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Currently I'm following along with the title named book. My code is as follows ( from the book so far as I can see it matches perfectly ). I apologize if this is something I could have easily searched for but I don't honestly understand the other answers well enough to figure it out on my end. Checking and rechecking the code from the book and what I have I don't see any errors I've made.

The MEAN Stack I'm using ( I wasn't aware there was more than one ) is MongoDB Express AngularJS and Nodejs

Error Msg ( Sorry I can't believe I initially forgot this )

```
e:\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:323
    throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
        ^
MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (e:\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:323:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\MEAN\app\controllers\users.server.controller.js:1:94)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\MEAN\app\routes\users.server.routes.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

If it makes any difference this is the directory structure

```
app/
    controllers/
        users.server.controllers.js
    models/
        user.server.model.js
    routes/
        users.server.routes.js
config/
    express.js
    mongoose.js
```

express.js

```
var config = require('./config'), 
express = require('express'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
compress = require('compression'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
session = require('express-session');

module.exports = function () {
    var app = express();
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        app.use(compress());
    }

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: false,
        secret: config.sessionSecret
    }));

    app.set('views', './app/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
    require('../app/routes/users.server.routes.js')(app);

    app.use(express.static('./public'));

    return app;
};
```

mongoose.js

```
var config = require('./config'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function() {
    var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);
    require('../app/models/user.server.model');
    return db;
}
```

user.server.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
UserSchema;

UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

users.server.controllers.js

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(user);
        }
    })
};
```

users.server.routes.js

```
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.route('/users').post(users.create);
}
```

Comment: sorry, but what's the issue?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing exactly?

Comment: also if this is a MEAN framework you should specify which one

Comment: ... Wow.. I can't believe I forgot to put the issue my apologies.

Comment: I must say I am annoyed at the down votes without giving me an opportunity to actually FIX it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a comma in server.js. Not sure what made me check it, but that was my issue.