# Required but not allocated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mean

I am teaching myself the MEAN-Stack and bought some literature to get into the topic.

In one book, the following code example is provided:

```
var config = require('./config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function() {
  var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);

  // require models
  require('../app/models/user.server.model');

  return db;
}
```

Now I am asking myself, how the line `require('../app/models/user.server.model');` is working, since there is no allocation ("=") to any variable. How and where is this model "loaded" or "included"?

Comment: Do you have access to the code of that model? It might be that the code is modifying some of the built-in objects provided by the language. So you only care about it's secondary effect instead of what it exports...

Comment: You can see the exact same structure in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609144/mean-web-development).  It is likely modifying some shared resources used by the database (e.g. loading the models).